# Laravel PHP doesn't save in database

Tags: php, laravel

My Model is:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class PedidoCliente extends Model
{
    protected $primaryKey = 'pdc_id';
    protected $table = 'scs_pedido_cliente';
}
```

My method is:

```
DB::beginTransaction();
try {

    $pedido                      = new PedidoCliente();
    $pedido->pdc_cod             = 1
    $pedido->pdc_cli_cod         = 1;
    $pedido->pdc_tpgp_cod        = 1;
    $pedido->pdc_total_frete     = 99;
    $pedido->pdc_total_com_frete = 199;
    $pedido->pdc_desc            = 'Compra produto x';
    $pedido->pdc_data_insert     = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
    $pedido->save();
    DB::commit();

 } catch (\Exception $e) {
    DB::rollback();
}
```

Don't return errors. I see the object and Primary Key when I print:

```
echo "<pre>";
print_r($pedido);
die("</pre>");
```

but it doesn't save in database.

Comment: You would need to add `protected fillable` in your model. Refer to this documentation: https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent#mass-assignment

Comment: @Mr.Kenneth You don't need to set `fillable` if you set properties with `->`

Comment: I changed the model, but don't works yet:

Comment: I add: protected $fillable = array('pdc_cod', 'pdc_cli_cod', 'pdc_tpgp_cod', 'pdc_total_frete', 'pdc_total_com_frete', 'pdc_desc', 'pdc_data_insert');

Comment: I use pgsql database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. A transaction had started in another function and it was not closing.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).